# Print the count of lines of the file into the first line of that file

Tags: sed

I am using sed to count the line numbers:

```
sed - n 'S=' file.txt
```

I want to print the result in the first line in `file.txt`.

Comment: Your sed is wrrong. The correct command is `sed -n '$=' file.txt`. Mind the difference bewteen `S=` (which is wrong) and `$=`

Comment: Would the count include the *old* number of lines, or N+1 as the new number of lines (with that count in the first line)?

Comment: Did you think of ```wc```? He is from POSIX and quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two passes through the file for that: one to count the lines, and a second one to insert the result at the beginning. `sed` isn't the optimal tool for that. Try:

`cat <(wc -l < file.txt) file.txt`

Comment: Without process substitution: `<file.txt wc -l | cat - file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmmm, seems like a "multi-cat-skinning" session. Assuming only the original number of lines is required how about ....

```
sed 1i$(< file wc -l) file
```

or

```
sed 1i$(sed -n "$=" file ) file
```

just `sed -i 1i....` to make the change permanent

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `sed`, **if** the line count is for *file* before the counter line is added:

```
sed -i -n '1h;1!H;${=;x;p}' file
```

---

How it works:

1. `-n`: turn off default printing.
2. `1h;1!H;`: move every line to the `h`old buffer.  (A simple `H` alone would almost work, but it would also produce an unwanted blank line.)
3. `${=;x;p}`: when `sed` reaches the last line, print the number of lines `=`.  Then e`x`change the fully loaded hold buffer with the pattern buffer, and print it.

Comment: This will work for GNU `sed` which can malloc extra memory for both the hold space and the pattern space but may fail for other versions of `sed` that have fixed sizes for hold and pattern spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution:

Append after the last line is easy:

```
awk '1; END{print NR}' file
```

We can use `tac` to add it to the first line:

```
tac file | awk '1; END{print NR}' | tac
```

This has the benefit over the other solutions that the file is opened  only once.

---

An `awk`-only alternative is a bit more complicated, we need to feed the file twice, first to count the lines, second to print the NR to the beginning:

```
awk 'FNR!=NR{if(FNR==1)print NR-1;print;}' file file
```

Another `awk`-only alternative (may be GNU only):

```
awk -ireadfile 'NR==1{print split(readfile(FILENAME), l, "\n")-1}1' file
```